# Is there anywhere to archive off unfinished Bugs and PBIs?

Tags: tfs, scrum

In TFS 2010 ss there anyway to move items to a state or something which won't appear in the Product Backlog?

We have 300+ Bugs and PBIs which are never going to be done at this stage. I've like to remove them from the Product Backlog but not delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that situation I'd add a new status such as "Not going to do it" or "Never".  Then assign those work items to that status.

Then I'd update the reports to specifically exclude anything with that status.

Answer (score 1):

The Product Backlog is displaying all PBIs that are not in Closed state therefore if you don't plan to use anymore these PBIs you can set them to Closed state.

Comment: I don't have a "Closed" state in my template. I'll have to edit the template I think and add a new state.

Comment: Indeed, the default Product Backlog of Scrum template is displaying the PBIs that are not in Done or Removed states (not Closed).